# How to write a proper constructor function extending the Array class

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, oop, constructor

### Scenario

I have the following piece of code:

```js
const composeMatrix = (nRow, nCol, filler) => Array(nRow).fill(Array(nCol).fill(filler));

class Matrix extends Array {
    constructor({ nRows = 3, nCols = 3, filler = 0 } = {}) {
        super(...composeMatrix(nRows, nCols, filler));
    }
    makeTranspose() {
        const mat = this;
        const column = mat[0];
        return column.map((_, i) => {
            return mat.map((row) => row[i]);
        });
    }
}
```

I'm instantiating a new `Matrix` like this:

```js
const mat = new Matrix({ nRows: 4, filler: 1 });
```

Logging `mat` to the console gives me as expected,

```js
Matrix(4) [ 
  [ 1, 1, 1 ], 
  [ 1, 1, 1 ], 
  [ 1, 1, 1 ],
  [ 1, 1, 1 ]
]
```

### Problem

Now when I call the `makeTranspose` method of the class, it returns me this:

```js
[ 
  Matrix(4) [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ], 
  Matrix(4) [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
  Matrix(4) [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ] 
]
```

Expected output:

```js
Matrix(3) [
  [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ], 
  [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ], 
  [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ]
]
```

What I figured is, the map function calls the constructor of this subclass every time while iterating through the array, which in turn calls `super`, which then calls the `composeMatrix` function and a new Matrix gets made.

How can I fix this?

- I want a `class` to extend `Array` with some added methods.
- The constructor needs to take some relevant parameters and function as expected.
- I don't want to add functions to the `prototype`.

Comment: Why do you want to extend `Array`? A matrix is not an array. This breaks the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A matrix is not an array. You're better off using [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

```js
Array.create = (length, mapping) =>
    Array.from({ length }, (value, index) => mapping(index));

class Matrix {
    constructor(rows, cols, data) {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.cols = cols;
        this.data = data;
    }

    static create(rows, cols, mapping) {
        const data = Array.create(rows, row =>
            Array.create(cols, col => mapping(row, col)));
        return new Matrix(rows, cols, data);
    }

    transpose() {
        const { rows, cols, data } = this;
        return Matrix.create(cols, rows, (row, col) => data[col][row]);
    }
}

const mat = Matrix.create(4, 3, (row, col) => 1);

console.log(mat.transpose());
```

Using a functional style of programming.

```js
const array = (length, mapping) =>
    Array.from({ length }, (value, index) => mapping(index));

const Matrix = (rows, cols, data) => ({ rows, cols, data });

const matrix = (rows, cols, mapping) =>
    Matrix(rows, cols, array(rows, row =>
        array(cols, col => mapping(row, col))));

const transpose = ({ rows, cols, data }) =>
    matrix(cols, rows, (row, col) => data[col][row]);

const mat = matrix(4, 3, (row, col) => 1);

console.log(transpose(mat));
```

Comment: I ended up doing something along these lines. [Implementation](https://github.com/abhijit-hota/nyo). Thank you for your answer.